# Swift mac os - Re-enable a segmented control cell

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, swift

I'm trying to create a UI in which the user can select/deselect multiple items.
I choose to use an segemented control to do such a thing and it's perfect for that use.

The behavior I want it to have is 
1) an item must be set to disabled when clicked on
2) an item must be set to enabled when clicked on

I implemented step 1 but can't do step 2 as when the cell is set to disabled it won't send any event

Here's the code

```
    @IBOutlet weak var segBtnStrings: NSSegmentedControl!

    @IBAction func setStringState(sender: AnyObject) {
        var segment = sender.selectedSegment 
        var enable = segBtnStrings.isEnabledForSegment(segment)

        segBtnStrings.setEnabled(!enable, forSegment: segment)
    }
```

Comment: A disabled control element does exactly what it should when it is disabled: It does not react on interactions. It would be very irritating for the user if a disabled button could be tapped.

Comment: It's also very irritating not to be able to enable it back, which is exactly my problem here. Isn't there a built-in on/off mechanism somewhere for these controls ? Or do I have to build it myself ?